# Terminal can't be opened

Tags: nvidia, ssh, xorg, lightdm

I met a problem that the ssh can't display a GUI software in a server. I changed the configuration of Xorg by modifying the file
`/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf`
as follows:

```
[Seat:*]
xserver-command=X -core +iglx
```

So now comes the problem, I lost the terminal (it can't be open, I could only use tty mode the change configuration) even though I changed it back the initial config:

```
[Seat:*]
# Dump core
xserver-command=X -core
```

Comment: If you restarted when you first changed it then that may be required again!

Comment: It should be some interferences between some softwares that I installed. After reinstalled the Ubuntu, this GUI issue can be solved with my trick posted in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling not to losing other important installations, I finally re-install the whole system and this trick by doing `+iglx` make the software appear without losing the Terminal.